# Autocomplete textview android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android developer.I want to know it is possible to set the selected item’s background of autocomplete text view drop-down menu.I try so many ways but the color change only when click.I can’t use spinner can use only autocomplete textview for school project. Below is example photo.

[image]

When drop-down pop up I want selected item with background color.please help!

Comment: consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add your code as well

Answer (score 0):

Your main layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Create an `drop_down_style.xml` layout in your resources. Add following view...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drop_down_text"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#C0C000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

Update your `ArrayAdapter` as following

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.add("1");
dataList.add("2");
dataList.add("3");
dataList.add("4");


AutoCompleteTextView view = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.drop_down_style, R.id.drop_down_text, dataList);
view.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: Sir,it doesnt work.

Comment: Is it causing error?, can you show me?

Comment: Sir,it doesnt change selected item background color when dropdown popup

Comment: Updated whole code,, have a look

Comment: Sir i am getting error at style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'

Comment: add this dependency in you `build.gradle (app)`